# What has hot shower to do with low blood pressure?

Tags: blood-pressure, blood

http://www.webmd.com/heart/understanding-low-blood-pressure-treatment

> **What Are the Treatments for Low Blood Pressure?**
>   ...
>
> Avoid prolonged exposure to hot water, such as hot showers and spas.

What has hot shower to do with low blood pressure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the body is exposed to hot temperatures, the normal response of the body is  dilation of the peripheral blood vessels so that the heat energy in the blood can be released into the external environment, increasing the rate at which the body cools down.

This dilatation also leads to decreased peripheral vascular resistance (blood pooling in the extremities, for instance), and thus a decrease in blood pressure.  Thus if one already suffers from low blood pressure, exposure to hot environments may temporarily exacerbate the problem.

http://www.colorado.edu/eeb/courses/1230jbasey/abstracts%202007/17.htm

Comment: Please don't be offended, but your reference looks like a high school experiment to me. It appears that there was one subject only (at least there was no mention of number), and the test consisted of placing the subject's hand in a beaker of water of differing temperatures. Your answer would be well served by use of better references.

Comment: @anongoodnurse, never underestimate the ability of high schoolers.

Comment: Haha! True... for long hot showers, they can't be surpassed. :D

Comment: the link does not working